# pygpu problem : DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, deep-learning, conda, theano, lasagne

When Trying to run a model in Theano on anaconda

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\dnn.py:184: UserWarning: Your cuDNN version is more recent than Theano. If you encounter problems, try updating Theano or downgrading cuDNN to a version >= v5 and <= v7.
  warnings.warn("Your cuDNN version is more recent than "
Loading nvrtc 11.0.
(Debug) ERROR 18: Could not load "nvrtc64_110.dll": The specified module could not be found.

Loading nvrtc 10.0.
Loading cuBLAS 10.0.
Using cuDNN version 7500 on context None
Mapped name None to device cuda: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (0000:01:00.0)
Loading network...
Input shape: (None, 1, 112, 112)
DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_fast_swapping.py", line 14, in <module>
    swapper = SWAPPER(vars, detector, weights_path + all_weights[1])
  File "d:\dubflix\video_module\video_module\fast_swap\api.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.aligner.loadNetwork(weights)
  File "d:\dubflix\video_module\video_module\fast_swap\src\FaceAlignment.py", line 133, in loadNetwork
    self.initializeNetwork()
  File "d:\dubflix\video_module\video_module\fast_swap\src\FaceAlignment.py", line 41, in initializeNetwork
    self.generate_network_output = theano.function([self.data], [self.prediction])
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 317, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1841, in orig_function
    fn = m.create(defaults)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1715, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 699, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1091, in make_all
    impl=impl))
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 955, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 858, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1217, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1157, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1624, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1191, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1527, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2422, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 327, in dlimport
    assert fullpath.startswith(rval.__file__)
AttributeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', GpuDnnConv{algo='small', inplace=True, num_groups=1}(GpuContiguous.0, GpuContiguous.0, GpuAllocEmpty{dtype='float64', context_name=None}.0, GpuDnnConvDesc{border_mode='half', subsample=(1, 1), dilation=(1, 1), conv_mode='conv', precision='float64', num_groups=1}.0, Constant{1.0}, Constant{0.0}), '\n', "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__file__'", "[GpuDnnConv{algo='small', inplace=True, num_groups=1}(<GpuArrayType<None>(float64, 4D)>, <GpuArrayType<None>(float64, (False, True, False, False))>, <GpuArrayType<None>(float64, 4D)>, <CDataType{cudnnConvolutionDescriptor_t}>, Constant{1.0}, Constant{0.0})]")
```

The important version informations are :

Anaconda (python 3.7)

Theano : 1.0.4 (latest from the master branch)

pygpu : 0.7.6 (installed from conda)

CUDA : 10.0

CUDNN : 7.6.5

I've checked the model loading without gpu and it works.

.theanorc.txt is like this:

```
[global]
device = cuda

[gcc]
cxxflags = -I"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin"

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0
```

```
conda list -n env
```

gives

```
# packages in environment at F:\anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
_pytorch_select           1.1.0                       cpu
absl-py                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2020.02                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0
astropy                   4.0              py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
audio-module              0.0.1                     dev_0    <develop>
audioread                 2.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.1.7            py37he774522_0
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0
bitarray                  1.2.1            py37he774522_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
blosc                     1.16.3               h7bd577a_0
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
boto3                     1.12.40                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.15.40                  pypi_0    pypi
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37h2a96729_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.14.0           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               1.3.0                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
cmake                     3.14.0               h33f27b4_0
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h62dcd97_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0
cryptography              2.8              py37h7a1dbc1_0
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h74a9793_0
curl                      7.68.0               h2a8f88b_0
cvlib                     0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.15          py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37he774522_0
dask                      2.11.0                     py_0
dask-core                 2.11.0                     py_0
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0
distributed               2.11.0                   py37_0
dlib                      19.19.0                  pypi_0    pypi
docopt                    0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
face-recognition          1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
face-recognition-models   0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
flake8                    3.7.9                    py37_0
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
fsspec                    0.6.2                      py_0
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0
gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.4.0            py37he774522_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
grpcio                    1.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
hypothesis                5.5.4                      py_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0
importlib_metadata        1.5.0                    py37_0
imutils                   0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
inaspeechsegmenter        0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2020.0                      166
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.12.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.14.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.11.1                     py_0
jmespath                  0.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.9.1                      py_0
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0
jupyterlab                1.2.6              pyhf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-vggface             0.6                      pypi_0    pypi
keyring                   21.1.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
krb5                      1.17.1               hc04afaa_0
lasagne                   0.2.dev1                 pypi_0    pypi
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.68.0               h2a8f88b_0
libgpuarray               0.7.6                hfa6e2cd_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libpython                 2.1                      py37_0
librosa                   0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_0
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
llvmlite                  0.31.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.5.0            py37h1350720_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-binutils            2.25.1                        5
m2w64-bzip2               1.0.6                         6
m2w64-crt-git             5.0.0.4636.2595836               2
m2w64-gcc                 5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-ada             5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-fortran         5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-objc            5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-headers-git         5.0.0.4636.c0ad18a               2
m2w64-isl                 0.16.1                        2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libmangle-git       5.0.0.4509.2e5a9a2               2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-make                4.1.2351.a80a8b8               2
m2w64-mpc                 1.0.3                         3
m2w64-mpfr                3.1.4                         4
m2w64-pkg-config          0.29.1                        2
m2w64-toolchain           5.3.0                         7
m2w64-tools-git           5.0.0.4592.90b8472               2
m2w64-windows-default-manifest 6.4                           3
m2w64-winpthreads-git     5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-zlib                1.2.8                        10
mako                      1.1.2                      py_0
markdown                  3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py37_0
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h64f37c6_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2020.0                      166
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0
mock                      4.0.1                      py_0
more-itertools            8.2.0                      py_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h74a9793_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
munkres                   1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0
networkx                  2.4                        py_0
ninja                     1.9.0            py37h74a9793_0
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0
numba                     0.48.0           py37h47e9c7a_0
numexpr                   2.7.1            py37h25d0782_0
numpy                     1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
opencv-python             4.2.0.34                 pypi_0    pypi
openpyxl                  3.0.3                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_4
packaging                 20.1                       py_0
pandas                    1.0.1            py37h47e9c7a_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
paramiko                  2.7.1                      py_0
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0
path.py                   12.4.0                        0
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    7.0.0            py37hcc1f983_0
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
progressbar               2.5                      pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.3                      py_0
protobuf                  3.11.3                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.6.7            py37he774522_0
py                        1.8.1                      py_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pyannote-algorithms       0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
pyannote-core             3.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyannote-parser           0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37he774522_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0
pydub                     0.23.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygame                    1.9.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0
pygpu                     0.7.6           py37hc8d92b1_1000    conda-forge
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0
pynacl                    1.3.0            py37h62dcd97_0
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py37ha925a31_0
pyopengl                  3.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyro4                     4.79                     pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.15.7           py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h1da0976_0
pytest                    5.3.5                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.8.0                      py_0
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.2                      py_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0
python-language-server    0.31.7                   py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.4.0           py3.7_cuda101_cudnn7_0    pytorch
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1000
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py37_0
pyyaml                    5.3              py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37ha925a31_0
qdarkstyle                2.8                        py_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.6.1                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1
resampy                   0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
rope                      0.16.0                     py_0
rtree                     0.9.3            py37h21ff451_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37he774522_0
s3transfer                0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h47e9c7a_0
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9439919_0
seaborn                   0.10.0                     py_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
serpent                   1.30.2                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                45.2.0                   py37_0
sidekit                   1.3.6.6                  pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
simplejson                3.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
soundfile                 0.10.3.post1             pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py37_0
spectralcluster           0.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinx                    2.4.0                      py_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.0                      py_0
spyder                    4.0.1                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            1.8.1                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.13           py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.31.1               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.11.0           py37he774522_0
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0
tbb                       2020.0               h74a9793_0
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0
tensorboard               1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
theano                    1.0.4+51.gf1e4ec47c          pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
torchvision               0.5.0                py37_cu101    pytorch
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_3
tqdm                      4.42.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
typing-extensions         3.7.4.2                  pypi_0    pypi
ujson                     1.35             py37hfa6e2cd_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
video-module              0.0.1                     dev_0    <develop>
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
watchdog                  0.10.2                   py37_0
wcwidth                   0.1.8                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
webrtcvad                 2.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  1.0.0                      py_0
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xarray                    0.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.2.7                      py_0
xlwings                   0.17.1                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      2.2.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? (`conda list -n env_name`)

Comment: @AMC I've edited the comment with the output of conda list -n env

Comment: Can you run at least a basic theano example in the gpu? Like the one appears here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-theano-with-gpu

Comment: Yes that example works, does that mean that there's a problem with the model? But it works fine on cpu.

Comment: Well, now we know it's not about getting to run code in the gpu, but maybe a bug on one module or something related to the AttributeError at the end of your log, or maybe a missing DLL. Can you track where the AttributeError is happening?

Comment: I've updated the question with the complete traceback. Looks like it breaks on the model initialization of the output layer.

Comment: Well, I guess that's a dead end for me. But if it works on cpu but no gpu you can try with a smaller initial case maybe? Or you can check the forums of each module involved.

Comment: I also spent some days on this theano configuration stuff. I also gave up after a while... just a few recommendations for you. In the configuration file add `  config.dnn.enabled=True` and include cudnn  path, details here http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html. besides that the problem, as far as I understood also for my case, was the version of theano and cuda modules.since theano is stopped to be improved, newer versions of cuda are not compatible with theano anymore. I hope this helps.good luck, and let us know if it works, I am also curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Create two different virtual environments. One for the CPU and another for the GPU. In the CPU install the TensorFlow CPU and in the GPU use the TensorFlow GPU. See if it works well separately.

Comment: The problem isn't with tensorflow, it's with theano or pygpu